# Problem with associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been working on my Rails app and I am stuck with some associations that I can't get my head around.

Here are my models:

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Item Model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :event
end
```

When I head into the rails console and do something like this:

```
> User.last.events.last.items
```

I get an error like this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: items.event_id: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE ("items".event_id = 1)
```

I have set my migrations like this:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.string :name
      t.integer :event_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :items, :event_id
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :items
  end
end
```

Is it something to do with my associations and the way that I have laid it out?
Or is the the depth of the associations?

I hope that I've provided enough information.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you verified that the column actually exists in the database?

Comment: Yep, the column exists on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you double check that you've run your migration (rake db:migrate).

It shouldn't matter, but you might also try "t.references :event" instead of "t.integer :event_id".

Comment: I had a problems with the test database, i had to purge it and then prepare it again. God I'm such a noob... Thanks for everyone that helped